# On double summation with Mathematica

Tags: symbolic, warning-messages, summation

Today I wanted to evaluate this sum using Mathematica:

$$f(a,b):=\sum_{(k,l)\in\mathbb{Z}^2,\ l\ne0}\frac{1}{(2 i k a \pi + 
   l b) (2 i (k - l) a \pi + l b)}$$

```
Sum[ If[ l == 0, 0, 
1/((2 I k a \[Pi] + l b) (2 I (k - l) a \[Pi] + l b))
], {l, -Infinity, Infinity}, {k, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

And the result I am given is 0.

However, if I give specific values to $a, b$ and then evaluate the sum numerically, I obtain values different to $0$, as, for $a= 30, b=2$:

```
Sum[If[l == 0, 0, 
N[1/((2 I k 30 \[Pi] + l 2) (2 I (k - l) 30 \[Pi] + l 2))]]
, {l, -1000, 1000}, {k, -1000, 1000}]
```

Obtaining the output:

```
0.000137911 + 2.53623*10^-6 I
```

Plotting the sum with $b=2$:

```
Plot[Abs[Sum[
If[l == 0, 0, 
a^2/((2 I k a \[Pi] + l 2) (2 I (k - l) a \[Pi] + l 2))]
, {l, -70, 70}, {k, -70, 70}]], {a, 15, 100}]
```

Seems that $|f|=O(\frac{1}{a^2}), f \ne 0$.

What it wrong with the symbolic calculation?

Comment: Indeed, easy to notice that at `a=0` the sum transforms into `Sum[If[l == 0, 0, 1/l^2], {l, -Infinity, Infinity}, {k, -Infinity, Infinity}]`. Since `Sum[If[l == 0, 0, 1/l^2], {l, -Infinity, Infinity}]==\[Pi]^2/3` the first sum is infinitely large, rather than zero.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch you mean $\pi^2/6$ ?

Comment: @Alexei Boulbitch : The case $a=0$ is special.

Comment: That is true, we may assume that both $a, b$ are positive reals. In spite of that, why is Mathematica giving 0 as an output and how can I get it to solve the sun correctly?

Comment: IMPO, this is rather a math question than a Mathematica question. The convergence of double series depending on parameters is a complex topic. Ask your question at https://math.stackexchange.com and/or https://mathoverflow.net .

Comment: @user64494 This is simple, as soon as (i) the result s=0 claimed by OP has been confirmed on my machine for any a and b, and (ii) I have shown that with a=0 one finds s=Infinity, this shows that there is a contradiction, whether a=0 is a special case, or not.

Comment: @Okkes Dulgerci Summation on my machine yields π^2/3.

Comment: @Alexei Boulbitch: This is not so simple: the Sum command produces a generic result.

Comment: @Alexei Boulbitch My bad. It is from $-\infty$ to  $\infty$. So it is double.

Comment: Thank you for the help received. Then, Are you claiming that unless $a=0$, the sum is always 0? And why can I get a non-zero plot of it?

Comment: If your comment is addressed to me, first,  I don't see any plot in your question; second, I don't claim that the sum under consideration equals zero for arbitrary positive values of the parameters; third, you cut the sum when calculating it (therefore, the partial sum can be different from the sum). I prefer arguments over emotional claims.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. First, I was talking about the plot command at the end of the question. Second, I was refering about @Alexei Boulbitch comment ,where he says that the sum equals 0 for arbitrary a. Third, I know that I am cutting the sum when calculating it, but increasing the nunber of terms is not reflected in the result tending to 0, hence my question about the validity of either the numerical approximation or the symbolic result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us put `a=1/(2*\[Pi])` and `b=1` in order to work with a concrete series. 
Next, let us use `n` instead of your`l`
 (The use of `l` is not convenient because of its similarity to the imaginary unit `I` and the unit `1`.).
True series are absolutely convergent series (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics) ,especially the  Absolute convergence section, 
as a first reading).
Let us calculate (notice that the terms of the series are complex-valued)

```
FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[Abs[1/((I*k + n)*(I*(k - n) + n))]], 
 Assumptions -> k \[Element] Reals && n \[Element] Reals]
```

> 1/Sqrt[(k^2 + n^2) (k^2 - 2 k n + 2 n^2)]

The sum of `1/Sqrt[(k^2 + n^2) (k^2 - 2 k n + 2 n^2)]` over all the integer values of `k` and all the integer values of `n` but zero
can be split into two sums. Let us consider one of these

```
Sum[1/Sqrt[(k^2 + n^2) (k^2 - 2 k n + 2 n^2)], {n, 1, Infinity}, {k, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

.Mathematica 11.3.0.0 returns it unevaluated on my comp. However, arguments similar to used in the integral test show
that this sum is of the same quantity as the double improper integral

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[(k^2 + n^2) (k^2 - 2 k n + 2 n^2)],{n,1,Infinity},{k,-Infinity,Infinity}]
```

See a typical plot

```
Plot3D[1/Sqrt[(k^2 + n^2) (k^2 - 2 k n + 2 n^2)], {k, 10, 11}, {n, 9,  12}]
```

[image]

to this end.

The above integral is divergent. This is clear if one switches to polar coordinates by (the `r` multiplier is the Jacobean)

```
1/Sqrt[(k^2 + n^2) (k^2 - 2 k n + 2 n^2)]*r /. {n -> r*Sin[\[Phi]], k -> r*Cos[\[Phi]]}//FullSimplify
```

> $$\frac{\sqrt{2} r}{\sqrt{-r^4 (2 \sin (2 \phi )+\cos (2 \phi )-3)}} $$

Therefore, the sum of the series under consideration has no sense. Maybe, its sum exists as some generalized sum.
In view of it  the result

```
Sum[1/((I*k + n)*(I*(k - n) + n)), {n, 1, Infinity}, {k, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> 0

is not reliable, in particular, the sum may depend on the order of the terms.
It should be noticed that

```
Sum[1/((I*k + n)*(I*(k - n) + n)),  {k, -Infinity,  Infinity},{n, 1, Infinity}]
```

returns unevaluated.